# How to return an extended object (subclass)? Actually, how to return the exact object which has been passed to a method?

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, subclass, return-type

I have an abstract class `UIObject` looking the following:

```
public abstract class UIObject {
    private final int tabOrder;

    public UIObject(int tabOrder) {
        this.tabOrder = tabOrder;
    }

    public int getTabOrder() {
        return this.tabOrder;
    }
}
```

and there are some objects which have `UIObject` as superclass.

In some service class I've also got a method `goTo()` which looks like this:

```
public UIObject goTo(UIObject object) {

    //some fancy code here

    return object;
}
```

Now, I want to return the specific object which has been passed to the function. (I know, this sounds stupid, but it's got a senseful reason, trust me.) But since the passed objects are all different subclasses of `UIObject`, this method does not work that way.

I strongy believe, I have done something like this before, thus I think this is an easy thing. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: BY "return the specific object" do you mean return an object of the same class as the one passed in?  If so the answer below with generics is your man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want such invocation of that method to work:

```
UIObjectSub obj = goTo(new UIObjectSub());
```

You have to make that method generic:

```
public <T extends UIObject> T goTo(T object) {
    //some fancy code here
    return object;
}
```

Now if you invoke that method passing an object of some subclass, the type parameter `T` will be inferred as that subclass type.

Comment: Oh yes! That's what I was searching for. Like I wrote, I already did this a while ago. But I couldn't remember how this "<T> thing" worked, plus I was mixing in some other related stuff I did at that same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as @Rohit Jain already specified in his answer, method can be generic, but also you can cast objects to child classes. It is called `Upcasting`

Assume that

```
SubUIObject extends UIObject {}
```

As `goTo` returns a `UIObject` just upcast it back:

```
SubUIObject object = (SubUIObject) goTo(new SubUIObject());
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't like casting if not necassary. I already use this, but only as a workaround so far. Thanks though.

Comment: It is not really a workaround. Casting is widely used in java becase java is a static-typed language. There is nothing wrong in casting.

Comment: I know, badly expressed by me. I ment, in this situation, I consider casting a workaround, because to me it does not seem to be the best way in terms of usability and clean coding. It is of course an option, but I personally haven't casted a lot yet except for "simple" data types like numbers, strings, chars, because there was no need so far. I appreciate your objection though. :-)